# Use line breaks of retrieved NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, plist, property-list

I retrieve an `NSString` from a Property list and display it in a `UILabel`. The `NSString` already includes `\n` s, however the `UILabel` just displays them as text. How can I tell the `UILabel` to actually use the `\n` s as line breaks?

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Where do the line breaks need inserting?  You'll probably want to use NSString's `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`, or one of the other substring replacement methods, but beyond that we can't really help without knowing more.  Note that to "insert" strings you can use `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` using a zero-length range at the correct position.

Comment: Whit what would I replace the `occurrencesOfString` or the `charactersInRange`?

Comment: `@"\n"` is a line break, if that's what you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you type into a plist in the plist editor is interpreted as plain text. Try it... put a `'` into a field and right click -> view as "plain text" and you'll see it substitutes it for `&apos;`. Therefore you can't put \n into a plist because it thinks you're just typing text and will treat it as such. Instead of putting \n into your plist use Alt+Enter to get your newline. If you view this as a text file now you'll see \ns printed and new lines acctually shown in the text file.

Now when you output it it won't display \n it will just give it a new line.

Plus, as has been mentioned UITextField is only one line anyway and you probably would benefit from using UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, you are going to need a string that you can modify. To accomplish that, you can simply do:

NSMutableString* correctedPath = [path mutableCopy];

At that point, you can use -insertString:atIndex: to insert any characters you need.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong class here.

`UITextField` doesn't (for all that I know) support multi-line input. For that, you will need a `UITextView` (it has editing enabled by default). It should interpret `\n`'s without any problems. It also has a `lineBreakMode` property, if you want to make use of that.